# Best practice for converting java code used for copying assets files to cache folder in Android to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, android-assets

I am using this code for copying Asset files in Android to cache folder, the point is it was a Java code and I convert it to Kotlin but it looks more Java(ish) mostly around while loop:

```
val file = File("${cacheDir.path}/$fileName")

val dir = file.parentFile
dir.mkdirs()

val inputStream = assets.open(fileName)

val bufferedOutputStream = BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(file))

val buf = ByteArray(10240)
var num = inputStream.read(buf)
// Java version: while ((num = fi.read(buf)) > 0)
while (num > 0) {
    bufferedOutputStream.write(buf, 0, num)
    num = inputStream.read(buf)
}

bufferedOutputStream.close()
inputStream.close()
```

any expert who can make it more Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually after a full translate the code should looks like this:

```
val file = File("${cacheDir.path}/$fileName")

val dir = file.parentFile
dir.mkdirs()

val inputStream = assets.open(fileName).use { input ->
    val bufferedOutputStream = file.outputStream().buffered().use { output ->
        input.copyTo(output, 10240)
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of both [`Closeable.use`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) extension function, [some](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/output-stream.html) other [handy](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-output-stream/buffered.html)  extension functions and the [`copyTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/copy-to.html) function mentioned above by the dev to simplify the code to the maxes.

PS: `Closeable.use` should be the kotlin counterpart of the Java 7 try-with-resource construct, with far better simplicity.

Comment: WOW! Thanks, it was wonderful. I really like this new language. Just edited some part of your answer and will confirm as correct answer after peer review.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to rewrite this is to get rid of the `while` loop entirely and to replace it with the [copyTo standard library function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/copy-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this is class in kotlin

```
/**
* @fileName: path of file in assets folder
* For example: getPathFileFromAssets("fonts/text4.ttf") or 
*getPathFileFromAssets("text4.ttf")
*/

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Context.getPathFileFromAssets(fileName: String): String {

var tmpPath = cacheDir.resolve(fileName)

if (tmpPath.exists()) return tmpPath.absolutePath

if (fileName.contains("/")) {
    val folder = fileName.split("/")[0]
    File(cacheDir, folder).also {
        if (it.exists().not()) {
            it.mkdirs()
        }
    }
}
tmpPath = File(cacheDir, fileName).also {
    it.outputStream()
        .use { cache ->
            assets.open(fileName)
                .use { it.copyTo(cache) }
        }
}
return tmpPath.absolutePath
}
```

use in Activity

```
try {
        val pathFile = getPathFileFromAssets("fonts/text5.ttf")
        val pathFile2 = getPathFileFromAssets("text5.ttf")
    } catch (e: IOException) {

    }
```

**NOTE**: You must include file **text5.ttf** in **assets folder** or **assets/fonts**